# Typescript: type error emerged on creating a "copy" constructor for class

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I would like to add a constructor to MyClass which takes 2 parameters, first one is instance of MyClass and second one is partial of MyClass non-function properties. Example is I have below MyClass

```
class MyClass {
    public variable1: string | undefined;
    public variable2: number | undefined;

    public function1(): void {
        console.log("log from function1.");
    }

    constructor(variable1: string, variable2: number) {
        this.variable1 = p1;
        this.variable2 = p2;
    }
}
```

and

```
const instance1 = new MyClass("a", 1);
const instance2 = new MyClass(instance1, { variable1: "b" });  <= now instance2 is instance with variable1 as "b" and variable2 remains 1
```

I changed MyClass as below

```
type PickByValue<T, ValueType> = Pick<T, {
    [Key in keyof T]-?: T[Key] extends ValueType ? never : Key;
}[keyof T]>;

type NonFunction = PickByValue<MyClass, Function>;
type UUKeys = keyof NonFunction;

class MyClass {
    public variable1: string | undefined;
    public variable2: number | undefined;

    public function1(): void {
        console.log(this.variable1 ?? "variable missing " + this.variable2?.toString() ?? "variable2 missing");
    }

    // First constructor
    constructor(variable1: string, variable2: number);
    // Second constructor
    constructor(p1: MyClass, p2: Partial<NonFunction>);
    // Implementation
    constructor(p1: MyClass | string, p2?: Partial<NonFunction> | number) {
        if (typeof p1 === 'string' && typeof p2 === 'number') {
            this.variable1 = p1;
            this.variable2 = p2;
        } else if (p1 instanceof MyClass && p2 && typeof p2 !== "number" && p2 satisfies Partial<NonFunction>) {
            for (const key of Object.keys(p1)) {
                if (typeof p1[key as keyof MyClass] !== "function") {
                    const k = key as UUKeys;
                    this[k] = p2[k] ?? p1[k];
                    ^^^^^^  <= ERROR: Type 'string | number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'undefined'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
                }
            }
        } else {
            this.variable1 = '';
            this.variable2 = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Error emerged confused my which I could not understand where undefined coming from as I already exclude `undefined` by converting key to `UUKeys`.

> Type 'string | number | undefined' is not assignable to type
> 'undefined'.   Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'

BTW, I am using Typescript v5.1.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes more sense if we look at the type of the key `k` and the value `v`.

```
if (typeof p1[key as keyof MyClass] !== 'function') {
  const k = key as UUKeys;  // 'variable1' | 'variable2'
  const v = p2[k] ?? p1[k]; // number | string | undefined
  this[k] = v;
}
```

- The key type is an enum of the properties of the class (that's not a function).
- The value type is a union of the types of all (non-function) properties of the class. In this case, the value can either be a number, string, or undefined.

If the key is `variable1` and the value is a number, it would be invalid. If the key is `variable2` and the value is a string, it would also be invalid. The only valid value for all properties is `undefined`.

---

In this case, you're already sure that the value has the correct type for the key, because `p2` is a partial of `MyClass`.

This is a typical case of "I know what I'm doing". Ease down on the type-checking.

```
(this as any)[key] = p2[key] ?? p1[key];
```

Comment: it does not work, switching to `this[key] = p2[key] ?? p1[key]` comes with error  - Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'MyClass'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'MyClass'

Comment: This is a case where you know better than typescript is able to figure out. I'm not getting that error, but you can just overwrite the check with `(this as any)[key] = p2[key] ?? p1[key];`.

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day! And I get your point on the problem.